# Conditional redirection issues

Tags: javascript

I have two conditional statements, one works and one doesn't. I've spent 3 days trying to figure out why. Hopefully someone here can spread some light on the problem.

the working statement - This one just toggles a div between display:none and :block

```
case 'addressSearch':
        var div = document.getElementById('addsearch');
           if (div.style.display !== 'block') {
                div.style.display = 'block';
            }
            else {
                div.style.display = 'none';
            }
```

This is the broken one - it's supposed to direct to a different page depending on the display property of a div. It redirects, but not depending on the value of display. I'm not sure why but the div.style.display is always an empty string.

```
function loginCheck(){
var div = document.getElementById('loin');
    if (div.style.display !== 'block') {
        window.location = '/login.shtml';
        }
    else {
        window.location = '/calendar.shtml';
    }
};
```

the css is #loin{display:block;} and the html is

```
    <div class="button" id="tmcb"  onclick="loginCheck()">To My Calendar</div>
```

Edit: The new if statement

```
        if (getComputedStyle(div, null).display !== 'block') { //something };
```

This works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `style` property returns what is assigned to the `style` HTML attribute and not the computed style from the CSS class that's assigned to the HTML element. If you use jQuery you could instead use `$('#loin').css('display')`.

If you don't want to use jQuery and you target IE9+, you can use [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle). I don't know the solution for IE8 and under, but google should help you out with that one.

You can also simply use `style="display: block"` instead of the CSS class and avoid all this computed style hassle.

Comment: Thank you. that put me on the right path. I'm trying to stay away from jquery for the time being to better my vanilla abilities.